# How to assign a variable to a variable without evaluation?

Tags: gnu-make

it is much easier to explain my problem by showing you some code.

Here it is:

```
FILES = $(F1)
A.FILES = $(FILES)

FILES = $(F2)
B.FILES = $(FILES)

F1 := file1
F2 := file2

all: a b

a: $(A.FILES)
    echo $^

b: $(B.FILES)
    echo $^

$(F1) $(F2):
    echo $@
```

The problem is calling `make a` prints file2, instead of file1. How could I maintain specifying A.FILES with a variable named FILES?
I know, := would do the job, but I may have F1 defined later.
I would like to have something which permits to have the following:

```
FILES = $(F1)
A.FILES <- FILES (assignation) such that A.FILES = $(F1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this.  You can do some tricky things to get it to work, like this:

```
F = $(F1)
A := $(value F)

F= $(F2)
B := $(value F)

F1 = foo
F2 = bar

$(eval A := $(A))
$(eval B := $(B))

all: ; @echo 'A=$(A) B=$(B)'
```

but there's no other way to do it.

**ETA**

Actually [alain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497574/how-to-assign-a-variable-to-a-variable-without-evaluation/55498058#comment97703267_55498058) gives an even better solution:

```
F = $(F1)
$(eval A = $(value F))

F= $(F2)
$(eval B = $(value F))

F1 = foo
F2 = bar

all: ; @echo 'A=$(A) B=$(B)'
```

Comment: You are the man! Thanks. Based on your answer, and on my example, I found this "assignation" to be effective $(eval A.FILES = $(value FILES))

Comment: Hah!  Good trick.  Yes that will do it as well.  I'll update my answer.